# Unable to connect to smtp.gmail.com from JavaMail based module

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

This has been working for years but since a few weeks, my JavaMail based modules report an error when trying to connect smtp.gmail.com:

The debugging output looks as follows:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.7
DEBUG: getProvider() returning
javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL false
MessagingException javax.mail.MessagingException: Could
not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
Certificate signature validation failed
```

I cannot seem to understand where this problem comes from and any help on how to track this down would be most appreciated.

Comment: You should provide your code. But take a look at www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/

Comment: Try updating openssl on that machine to refresh trusted certificates. Also, be aware that regular Gmail users can disable SMTP access altogether (not in thi case, though)

Comment: Of course the first question is "what changed?"  I'm guessing that something in your anti-virus or firewall changed and now it's intercepting messages between your application and Gmail.  Try the [JavaMail connection debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug) to figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if simply replacing the lib/security/cacerts file with a version of the file from the most current jdk would have solved the problem.